# .on ('mouseover') on d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, text, dom-events

I have a clarification question regarding the .on('mouseover') method in d3.
The code I have is:

```
svg.selectAll('text')
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .attr('x',function(d){
              return xScale(d[0]);
            })
            .attr('y',function(d){
              return yScale(d[1]);
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d[0] + ',' + d[1];
              })
            .style('visibility','hidden');
            .on('mouseover',...)
```

What kind of function shall I put instead of the `...` in the code to make the style of a single text tag become `visible` when hovering with the mouse?

I have checked different solutions but none of them work.
(One is: [d3 - trigger mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991680/d3-trigger-mouseover-event))

Moreover, I was wondering if what I thought about d3 workflow is corrected (I started to learn d3 only yesterday so be patient..):
`.selectAll` iterates through what it is given to it inside the `.data` argument.
At each iteration a text object(?) is created at the given position and with a given label. What does the `.style` refer to? The single object `.selectAll` iterates through? So are there multiple `.style` for each object iterated? And how to modify that object? Would `d3.select(this).style('visibility','visible')` be enough? (Looking at the link above it does not seem so...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need the following code:

```
.on("mouseover", function() { d3.select(this).style("visibility", "visible"); });
```

<strike>That said, hidden elements never get mouse events, so this code will never be triggered. You'll have to use another element that does receive events to trigger the text appearing. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707100/how-to-show-hidden-divs-on-mouseover).</strike>
As pointed out in the comments, you can use the `pointer-events` property to make non-visible elements receive mouse events.

This is what happens behind the scenes when you run this code:

- `svg.selectAll('text')` selects all `text` elements.
- `.data(dataset)` binds the data in `dataset` to those selected elements.
- `.enter()` chooses the enter selection. The enter selection contains all data items for which no matching DOM element was found, i.e. everything in `dataset` that has no matching `text` element.
- `.append('text')` appends a new `text` element for each of the items in the enter selection.

Everything else happens for each item in the enter selection as well. So you're setting the attributes, styles, etc for each of the added elements. If you pass a function when setting an attribute, it's evaluated with the data element that is bound to the particular DOM element (`d`).

Comment: The pointer-events property can be used to make hidden elements receive events.

Comment: You can't use pointer-events with invisible html, only with invisible svg elements (http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/pA5W5/1/). html elements only allow auto and none.

Comment: related to @RobertLongson's comment: [MDN's breakdown of all the `pointer-events` options, including which ones only apply to SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Thanks; I have actually found that playing with `opacity` solves the problem.